# Jetpack Compose set status bar color over ModalDrawer to transparent when open

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is my Modal drawer when open

[image]

Code to implement it

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
private fun TutorialContent() {
    ModalDrawerComponent()
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
private fun ModalDrawerComponent() {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val openDrawer: () -> Unit = { coroutineScope.launch { drawerState.open() } }
    val closeDrawer: () -> Unit = { coroutineScope.launch { drawerState.close() } }
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    ModalDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerContentHeader()
            Divider()
            ModelDrawerContentBody(
                selectedIndex,
                onSelected = {
                    selectedIndex = it
                },
                closeDrawer = closeDrawer
            )
        },
        content = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                ModalDrawerTopAppBar(openDrawer)
                ModalContent(openDrawer)
            }
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun ModalDrawerTopAppBar(openDrawer: () -> Unit) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text("ModalDrawer")
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = openDrawer) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        },
        actions = {}
    )
}


@Composable
fun ModalDrawerContentHeader() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(180.dp)
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(60.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.avatar_1_raster),
            contentDescription = null
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Text(text = "Android", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, fontSize = 22.sp)
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text(text = "android@android.com")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun ModelDrawerContentBody(
    selectedIndex: Int,
    onSelected: (Int) -> Unit,
    closeDrawer: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        modalDrawerList.forEachIndexed { index, pair ->

            val label = pair.first
            val imageVector = pair.second
            DrawerButton(
                icon = imageVector,
                label = label,
                isSelected = selectedIndex == index,
                action = {
                    onSelected(index)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun ModalContent(openDrawer: () -> Unit) {
    LazyColumn {

        items(userList) { item: String ->
            ListItem(
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    openDrawer()
                },
                icon = {
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(40.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape),
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.avatar_1_raster),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                },
                secondaryText = {
                    Text(text = "Secondary text")
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = item, fontSize = 18.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}

val modalDrawerList = listOf(
    Pair("My Files", Icons.Filled.Folder),
    Pair("Shared with Me", Icons.Filled.People),
    Pair("Starred", Icons.Filled.Star),
    Pair("Recent", Icons.Filled.AccessTime),
    Pair("Offline", Icons.Filled.OfflineShare),
    Pair("Uploads", Icons.Filled.Upload),
    Pair("Backups", Icons.Filled.CloudUpload),
)
```

What i actually desire is to have transparent status over the drawer as in the image below
[image]

Comment: what attempts have you made to do? what research have you done etc?

Comment: I wrote the snippet,  building a [Tutorial](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials), and inspecting a lot of codebases, i searched questions that contain  **ModalDrawer** keyword on stackoverflow, took image from [official page](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary) i also checked codelab samples and google sample projects. This question neither asked nor answered before and the answer on SO, and i haven't seen any answer to it with google search either.

Comment: And on top of that, i took image from android studio, and shrinked for it not cover most of the screen and downloaded offical image in case it might be changed in the future and uploaded it again.